# What are some good ways to reduce FID (First input delay) in isomorphic React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, isomorphic-javascript, isomorphic

FID for pointerdown event in very in my application. Its an Isomoprphic react application. Could anyone suggest some good ways to reduce it. Recently google search console has introduced speed (experimental). It's showing most of my website pages are slow because of high FID (> 300ms).

Comment: can you send your network waterfall (without caching) to help in your particular case

Comment: could you add info about your server side framework?

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce bundle size
- Use server side rendering (I guess you use it because you have an Isomorphic app)
- Use [Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)
- Check website with [google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) (it helps you to identify "the weakest" parts also this google service provides suggestions on how page may be improved)

Also I need more details about network waterfall (for example it can be big images (you can optimize it or use lazy load for your images) or another requests that can reduce fid)

Comment: Isomorphic react applications are serverside rendered. FID is usually high in serverside rendered apps how will it decrease FID?

Comment: I know. Yeah, Usually but not in your case. I just mentioned about it because it can help for someone

Comment: We have implemented route and well as component based splitting. We are also using lazy loading for image. For css we are using styled components. I don't think it we are experiencing high FID because of any of these issues.

Comment: do you use react ssr framework as next.js, gatsby etc?

Comment: No, we are not using any framework for server side rendering